# Extract number decimal in BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

How to extract a number after the decimal point using BigDecimal ?

> BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.valueOf(1548.5649);

result : extract only : 5649

Comment: Note: You should use `BigDecimal.valueOf("1548.5649");` instead because conversion between `double` and `BigDecimal` can cause weird side effects. If you need precision, avoid `double` and `float`.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I think you mean new BigDecimal("1548.5649") because there is no BigDecimal.valueOf(String) method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.valueOf(1548.5649);
BigDecimal result = d.subtract(d.setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR)).movePointRight(d.scale());      
System.out.println(result);
```

prints:

```
5649
```

Answer (score 6):

Try [BigDecimal.remainder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#remainder%28java.math.BigDecimal%29):

```
BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.valueOf(1548.5649); 
BigDecimal fraction = d.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
System.out.println(fraction);
// Outputs 0.5649
```

Comment: it's display : 1548.564900000000079671735875308513641357421875

Comment: As in other topics the result should be "5649" not "0.5649" , this is not the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
d.subtract(d.setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR));
```

[`setScale()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29) rounds the number to zero decimal places, and despite its name, does not mutate the value of `d`.

Answer (score 1):

If the value is negative, using `d.subtract(d.setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR))` will return a wrong decimal.

**Use this**:

```
BigInteger decimal = 
                d.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).movePointRight(d.scale()).abs().toBigInteger();
```

It returns `5649` for `1548.5649` or `-1548.5649`

Comment: If you are trying to use this to get the decimal of cash this wont work. 3.3 will give you 3 and not 30

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell which type you want as a result. The easiest way is probably to transform the BigDecimal into a String, and take a substring:

```
String s = d.toPlainString();
int i = s.indexOf('.');
if (i < 0) {
    return "";
}
return s.substring(i + 1);
```

Comment: This works only for a Locale that uses . as the decimal separator. But there are Locales which are using ,.

Comment: @BetaRide: I know that, I'm French speaking, and the comma is used here. But BigDecimal.toPlainString() is not locale-aware. It uses the dot as decimal separator whatever the locale is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with $$ and want to get the exact 2 decimals.
Example something .03 or .30 others solutions didn't do it.

(the toString would have done it but I tryed to avoid jumping to strings)

In my case I was needing both two numbers after the dot as I was storing the value into a devide using byte.

```
BigDecimal asoluteAmount = initialValue.abs();
byte result = (byte)(asoluteAmount.subtract(asoluteAmount.setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR)).multiply(new BigDecimal(100)).setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR).intValue());
```

Answer (score -3):

try to use `d.doubleValue()` to get the double value

Comment: it return a same number : 1548.5649